# How to print several copies of a large postscript file on a printer with little memory?

Tags: shell-script, memory, out-of-memory, postscript, hp-printer

I'm printing a postscript file containing a folder on my HP Laserjet 1320. I can print the folder one by one, but when I try to print a couple of them at one time, say 10, the printer doesn't have enough memory and signals an error. I guess this is due to the printing software adding up all 10 folders to be printed and sends them to the printer at once.

**How can I avoid running out of memory?**

*Possible solutions*:

- Write a script that prints one folder, then waits for 10 s and prints another one etc.
- Is there a setting in the printer driver that does ditto?

*Workarounds*:

- Push "reprint"-button in printer's jobs list several times to print more copies ... not very comfortable :)

Answer (score 0):

The simple script below will do it. It takes one argument: the number of copies you want to print. It creates a separate print jobs for each copy, thus circumventing the low error problem on the printer by feeding it one copy at a time.

```
#!/bin/bash
for run in $(seq $1); do
  lp -d hp-laserjet-1320-postscript-FUMA-FOLDER \
     -o sides=two-sided-short-edge fileToPrint.pdf
done
```

Shine on you crazy HP Laserjet